# How can I run a favourited application with a runtime argument?

Tags: 22.04

I have installed GitHub Desktop for Ubuntu but unfortunately I need to run it with the argument `--disable-gpu-sandbox` for it to work. This is achievable from the command line but I'd like to simply click it from my favourites bar, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Make a desktop short cut for it. https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-desktop-shortcut/

Answer (score 8):

You should edit the `.desktop` launcher file. These text files are what provide the icon on your favorites bar.

1. Find that `.desktop` launcher first. Depending on how you installed the application, the `.desktop` file may reside in any of the `applications` directories under one of the `XDG_DATA_DIRS`. You can see the list with the command `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS`. It will be under `/usr/share/applications` if you installed the program with the software center or using a downloaded `.deb` installation file.

   To find the launcher, using `find` may be quicker and more effective:

   ```
    find / -name '*.desktop' ! -path '/run/user*' -exec grep -H "Name=Github" {} \; 2>/dev/null
   ```

   In this example, I assumed the label of the icon is "Github desktop".
2. Assuming the file is `/usr/share/applications/github.desktop`, copy it to your local `~/.local/share/applications` directory. That copy will override the systemwide copy. Edit that copy and add your option to the command that is defined on the line starting with `Exec=`.